# How to download a package and its dependencies with aptitude?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dependencies, aptitude

I am trying to download some debian packages and their dependencies in a directory.

I tried using the command `aptitude download <package_name>` it downloaded the package without its dependencies.

How do I tell it to download the dependencies too?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory). Will the accepted answer work in your case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `apt-rdepends` to build the complete set of dependencies (recursively), including the main package, then download that:

```
apt-get download $(apt-rdepends "${package}" | grep -v ^\ )
```

(replacing `"${package}"` of course).

Comment: that's great, and it places a bunch of .debs into the current directory. But it can give errors like `E: Can't select candidate version from package c-compiler as it has no candidate` when there are virtual packages in the list.

Comment: That’s a good point, thanks for raising it; `apt-repends` also suffers from listing alternatives equally (for example, `cargo` is listed as depending on `gcc`, `clang` and `c-compiler`).

Answer (score 2):

A rather hackish way to do that is to have another utility (`apt-cache` in this example) list the package's dependencies:

```
# PACKAGE=nautilus; aptitude download $PACKAGE $(apt-cache depends "$PACKAGE" | grep Depends | awk -F ': ' '{print $NF}' | xargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier Way

`aptitude  -d -o Dir::Cache:archives=/home/alex/aptitude-test/ install alsaplayer` for exampel.