# How to download package not install it with apt-get command?

Tags: apt, download

```
sudo apt-get install pppoe
```

will download `pppoe` package and install it.

Is it possible to just download `pppoe` package and not install it with `apt-get` command?

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/ppp/ppp_2.4.7-1+4_amd64.deb
```

`ppp_2.4.7-1+4_amd64.deb`  is in the current directory now.

```
cd  /tmp
sudo  apt-get install  -d  ppp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ppp
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/346 kB of archives.
After this operation, 949 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Download complete and in download only mode
```

No  `ppp_2.4.7-1+4_amd64.deb` or ppp related package in /tmp.

```
sudo  find  /tmp  -name  ppp*
```

Nothing found.

Where is the package ppp in /tmp with command

```
cd  /tmp
sudo  apt-get install  -d  ppp
```

??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Newer versions can use

```
apt download pppoe
```

It will be downloaded into the current directory.

(For ubuntu-based distributions whose version >=18.04)

Comment: This was already covered in [Faheem’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408406/86440). There’s no need for `sudo`.

Answer (score 101):

Use `--download-only`:

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only pppoe
```

This will download `pppoe` and any dependencies you need, and place them in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. That way a subsequent `apt-get install pppoe` will be able to complete without any extra downloads.

Comment: Can you think of a way to specify the output directory for the downloaded package?

Comment: I've considered `apt-get download <package>`, but it doesn't download dependencies.

Comment: You should be able to change it by modifying `Dir::Cache` and `Dir::Cache::archives`, with the `-o` option.

Comment: Does not seem to work if the package is already installed

Comment: @Alexey yes, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313117/86440) for situations where the target package is already installed.

Answer (score 44):

Use this command:

```
apt-get download pppoe
```

This command let you download the package into the current directory.

For accessing installed `.deb` files, you can look in this path:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Comment: This *doesn’t* download dependencies, it only downloads the packages named in the arguments.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on Hamid's answer slightly, any of these three very similar commands will work if your only desire is to only download the specified package, and *nothing else*. (Your use case is not clearly stated, so it's unclear if that is what you want to do.) They all download the Debian binary package file corresponding to the specified binary Debian package to the current directory. Note that these commands will download only the binary package specified, and none of its dependencies. If you want the dependencies as well, use [the answer provided by Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408348/4671).

```
apt-get download ppoe

apt download ppoe

aptitude download ppoe
```

The first two command are part of the `apt` package, the third is part of the `aptitude` package. They are all functionally equivalent, as far as I know, though syntax and usage differences between `apt` and `aptitude` may cause you to prefer one of them under certain circumstances. And of course `apt` is a newer command than `apt-get` - it contains `apt-get` and `apt-cache` functionality while discarding some of the historical baggage.

Note also that if any of these commands find the file already in the current directory, they will not download it again. However, I'm not sure what criteria they use to check - or, in other words, how hard it is to fool them. A blank file doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

When working on one Ubuntu server that had no internet but accessible through the company intranet. Installing packages was challenging.

I created a script that will search the dependencies of a required package store them in a list, then go through the list to download other child dependencies because sometimes just one pass of dependency downloading was not enough. After it downloaded the dependencies it bundled them in a zip file that can be moved as a whole to the server. I called this script **pkgdownload**.

It can be found on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/wickerlabs/WickerScripts)

Here's an image of it at work:
[image]

Comment: Good job!  A nice additional feature would be the option to download `recommends` and `suggests` packages.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/117646/6227

Comment: Doesn't `apt-offline` already do this?

Comment: `apt-cache show apt-offline` suggests that `apt-offline` is good only for updating packages, not installing new ones.

Answer (score 2):

`apt` provides a source retrieval command - `apt source`.

```
$ apt source pppoe
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'rp-pppoe' as source package instead of 'pppoe'
Need to get 239 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://mirror.location.org/debian stretch/main rp-pppoe 3.12-1.1 (dsc) [1,708 B]
Get:2 http://mirror.location.org/debian stretch/main rp-pppoe 3.12-1.1 (tar) [224 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.location.org/debian stretch/main rp-pppoe 3.12-1.1 (diff) [13.2 kB]
Fetched 239 kB in 0s (1,241 kB/s)    
dpkg-source: info: extracting rp-pppoe in rp-pppoe-3.12
dpkg-source: info: unpacking rp-pppoe_3.12.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking rp-pppoe_3.12-1.1.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: applying 01_auto_ifup.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 02_change_mac_option.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 03_man_pages.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 04_ignore_broadcasted_pado_packets.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 05_change_default_timeout.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 06_typo_fixes.patch
```

For this to work, you need a source repository in your `sources.list` or `sources.list.d` directory (`/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Such a line would look something like (replace with suitable mirror and repository sections):

```
deb-src http://mirror.location.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the poster was asking for a command to download a Debian binary package, not the Debian sources. So this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The command to download with missing dependencies and in the current folder is:

`sudo apt install --download-only pppoe -o Dir::Cache::archives=./`

This will modify the `archives` folder only for this call.

`Dir::Cache` is the folder with `apt update` content files and is working to backup them too:

`sudo apt update -o Dir::Cache=/another_folder`. For this example with `pppoe` is enough to copy `pkgcache.bin` to `/another_folder`.

`sudo apt install --download-only pppoe -o Dir::Cache::archives=./ -o Dir::Cache=/another_folder` will read contents from `/another_folder` and download pppoe with dependencies in the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the package file into a specific directory with `wget`:

```
$ wget -O ~/Downloads/ppp_2.4.7-1+4_amd64.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/ppp/ppp_2.4.7-1+4_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with me

```
sudo apt-get reinstall --download-only <your software>
```

for example

```
sudo apt-get reinstall --download-only ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

For accessing installed .deb files, you can look in this path:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```