# Is it possible to install Debian packages in Fedora?

Tags: debian, fedora, apt, dpkg

I am trying to write a script that uses some not shell builtin commands (such as `expect`) and I am plannig to use it offline.

Normally, I can install `expect` in Fedora using `sudo yum install expect` or Ubuntu using `sudo apt install expect`.

But I want to download `expect` package and all it's depends using `sudo apt-cache depends expect` (after learning depends use...) `sudo apt download <depends>`.

I tried it and downloaded some `.deb` files. And I also tried this:

1. Extract `data.tar` files from `.deb` files ( I didn't want to use `dpkg -i <some_pkg.deb>` because I didn't succeded all time and I want to use it in Fedora -which is not using `dpkg`-).
2. Extract all files using `tar -xhf data.tar -C ~/demo`
3. Finally I manually copy all files in system dirs using `cp -rPn ~/demo/bin/* /bin ~/demo/etc/* /etc ...`

But when I do this -espacially using this `.deb` type packages inside Fedora-, I got `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error and my system is dead.

I know I am trying not recommended and dangerous approach to achieve my goal, but is there a way to this (espacially backup a command eg. `/usr/bin/expect` and all its depends) to use it offline?

Answer (score 5):

You can try `alien` it will convert packages between different package systems.

It's not bulletproof, dependencies will apply and there might be other issues, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 5):

Don’t try to mix and match packages across distributions, it’s unlikely to work reliably except in the very simplest of cases.

Instead, use the target distribution’s tools. You’ve found out how to download packages and their dependencies on Debian-based distributions; this is also possible on Fedora-based distributions. To download `expect` and *all* its dependencies, create a temporary root and a temporary download directory, and tell `dnf` to download the packages needed to install `expect` in the temporary root:

```
mkdir /tmp/expectroot
mkdir /tmp/expectdeps
sudo dnf install --installroot /tmp/expectroot \
                 --downloadonly --downloaddir /tmp/expectdeps \
                 --releasever 32 expect
```

(replacing “32” as appropriate).

You will then find all the packages you need for an offline installation, regardless of the existing dependencies on the target system, in `/tmp/expectdeps`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try it right away. How can I do this in Debian with `dpkg` or `apt`?

Comment: Oh, I thought you’d done that already. To download a Debian package on Debian with all its dependencies, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313117/86440).